# jqgrid cell validation and restore cell data implementation

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

New to jquery and trying to use jqgrid for its cell editing features, but unable to understand how to implement validating the cell data on edits, and if it fails restore back to the original value.  Here is where I'm currently at ...

```
function goalsTable(dept, team, goal, effDt) {

var grid = $('#tblEmployeeGoals');
$('#tblEmployeeGoals').jqGrid(
{

    url: "api/data/GetEmployeeGoals_DT?dep=" + dept + "&team=" + team + "&goal=" + goal + "&effdt=" + effDt,
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    colNames: ["Name",
        "Payroll Id",
        "Goal Name",
        "Effective Date",
         "Amount",
         "empgoalid",
         "Team",
         "Comments",
         "departmentid",
         "goaltypeid",
            ],
    colModel: [
        { name: "name", index: "Name", "hidden": false, editable: true, edittype: "text" }
        , { name: "payrollid", index: "Payroll Id", "hidden": true, editable: false }
        , { name: "goalname", index: "Goal Name", "hidden": false, editable: false }
        , { name: "effDate", "hidden": false, editable: false }
        , { name: "goalval", "hidden": false, editable: true}
        , { name: "empgoalId", "hidden": true, editable: false }
        , { name: "primarysupervisor", "hidden": true, editable: false }
        , { name: "comments", "hidden": false, editable: true }
        , { name: "departmentid", "hidden": true, editable: false }
        , { name: "goaltypeid", "hidden": true, editable: false }
    ]
    , cellEdit: true, // TRUE = turns on celledit for the grid.
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
       //was thinking I could get the original value before editing 
       // and if validation fails then replace the new value with this original 
        origval = value;
        orow = iRow;
        ocol = iCol;
    },
    beforeSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        //check value before committing it
        if (cellname = "goalval") {
            if (!validateData("number", value) ) {

                grid.jqGrid('restoreCell', iRow, iCol, true);
            }
        }

    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another developer and I worked it out by using a global variable that is an array of row data objects.

When a user edits the row the drawCallBack is triggered.  Here we load the row data values into an object and check to see if the keyval (payrollid) exists in the array.  If it does then we update the array object with the new val, otherwise we add the object to the array.

This way when the user presses update we pass the array object that only includes the rows that had changes occur.

```
$( '#tblEmpGoal' ).show();
var EGtble = $( '#tblEmployeeGoals' ).dataTable
( 
    {
        processing: true,
    responsive: false,
    destroy: true,
    filter: false,
    ajax: "api/data/GetEmployeeGoals_DT?dep=" + dept + "&team=" + team + "&goal=" + goal + "&effdt=" + effDt
    , drawCallback: function ()
    {
        $( '#tblEmployeeGoals tbody td:nth-child(4),td:nth-child(5)' ).editable( 
                    function ( cellVal )
                    {
                        if ( cellVal != this.revert )
                        {
                            // currentCellObject = $( this );

                            ind = $( this ).index()
                            //Validate amount is a numeric value
                            if ( ind == 3 )
                            {
                                var isNum = validateData( "number", cellVal );
                                //amtCellVal = cellVal;
                                if ( !isNum )
                                {
                                    $( '#error' ).html( "<strong> ! Please enter a numeric value.</strong>" ).show();
                                    setTimeout( function ()
                                    {
                                        $( "#error" ).fadeOut();
                                    }, 4000 );
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }

                            var row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
                            row[0].cells[2].innerHTML = $( '#EGEffectiveDateInput' ).val();

                            //Highlight cell to show edit
                            $( this ).addClass( 'red' );

                            //Get visible value
                            //  alert( cellVal ); 

                            //Get invisible column historical values using the old .dataTable library

                            var rowData = EGtble.fnGetData( EGtble.fnGetPosition( this )[0] );

                            tmg = new Object();
                            tmg.payrollid = rowData.payrollid;
                            tmg.departmentid = rowData.departmentid;
                            tmg.goaltypeid = rowData.goaltypeid;
                            tmg.goalname = rowData.goalname;
                            tmg.empgoalId = rowData.empgoalId;
                            tmg.primarysupervisor = rowData.primarysupervisor;
                            tmg.name = rowData.name;

                            var effectDate = $( '#EGEffectiveDateInput' ).val();
                            if ( effectDate != rowData.effDate )
                                tmg.effDate = effectDate;
                            else
                                tmg.effDate = rowData.effDate;

                            //Edit the Amount and Comments columns and effective date
                            if ( tmgArray.length > 0 )
                            {
                                doPush = true;
                                for ( i = 0; i < tmgArray.length; i++ )
                                {
                                    if ( tmgArray[i].payrollid == rowData.payrollid )
                                    {
                                        doPush = false;
                                        if ( ind == 3 )
                                        {
                                            tmgArray[i].goalval = cellVal;
                                        }
                                        else if ( ind == 4 )
                                        {
                                            tmgArray[i].comments = cellVal;
                                        }

                                        //check if the date changed and update this field as well
                                        var effectDate = $( '#EGEffectiveDateInput' ).val();
                                        if ( effectDate != tmgArray[i].effDate )
                                            tmgArray[i].effDate = effectDate;
                                        //else
                                        //    tmgArray[i].effDate = rowData.effDate;
                                    } //endif
                                } //end for
                            } //end if len array > 0
                            else
                            {
                                doPush = true;
                            }

                            //if a matching payroll Id not found in existing array or array is empty we add new row
                            if ( doPush )
                            {
                                if ( ind == 3 )
                                {
                                    tmg.goalval = cellVal;
                                    tmg.comments = rowData.comments;
                                }
                                else if ( ind == 4 )
                                {
                                    tmg.comments = cellVal;
                                    tmg.goalval = rowData.goalval;
                                }
                                tmgArray.push( tmg );
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cellVal = this.revert;
                        }
                        return cellVal;
                    },
                    {
                        "placeholder": ""
                         , "callback": function ( sValue, y )
                         {
                             //  Redraw the table from the new data on the server */
                             console.log( sValue );
                             //  EGtble.draw( true );
                         }
                        , onblur: 'submit'
                        //  }
                    } );
    }
    , columns: [
         { data: "name", "title": "Name", "visible": true }
        , { data: "payrollid", "title": "Date", "visible": false }
        , { data: "goalname", "title": "Goal Type", "visible": true }
        , { data: "effDate", "title": "Effective Date", "visible": true }
        , { data: "goalval", "title": "Amount", "visible": true }
        , { data: "empgoalId", "title": "Employee Goal ID", "visible": false }
        , { data: "primarysupervisor", "title": "Team", "visible": false }
        , { data: "comments", "title": "Comments", "visible": true }
        , { data: "departmentid", "title": "Department", "visible": false }
        , { data: "goaltypeid", "title": "Goal Type Id", "visible": false }
        ],
    columnDefs: [{
        render: function ( data, type, row )
        {
            var selectedDate = new Date( data );
            return ( ( selectedDate.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + selectedDate.getDate() + '/' + selectedDate.getFullYear() );
        },
        targets: [3]
    }]
} );
```